# Complemented subspaces of $C(\beta\mathbb N\times \beta\mathbb N)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, stone-cech-compactification

> **Problem.** Is there any complemented subspace in the Banach space $C(\beta\mathbb N\times\beta\mathbb N)$, not isomorphic to $c_0$, $c_0\oplus C(\beta\mathbb N)$, $C(\beta\mathbb N)$, $c_0(C(\beta\mathbb N))$, $C(\beta\mathbb N\times\beta\mathbb N)$?

(The problem was posed by Anastasia & Leandro in August 2015 on [page 16](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=16) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/)).